# If the training loss is always lower than the validation loss, does that indicate overfitting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

[image]

I am training a CNN model on MNIST data, and setting the validation split = 0.2, while the batch size = 128 and epochs = 5. After training the model I am getting an accuracy on train and validation greater than 99%. When I am plotting the learning curve, I am getting a graph with very low training and validation loss, but the training loss is always higher than the validatin loss. I wanted to understand is this the case of overfitting?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say but if I squint I would say you started over-fitting at epoch 2. Having validation loss > train loss is fairly standard. The larger the gap the worse generalization but if they're both the same I'd be suspicious that your split is leaking info from train to test (i.e. samples from the same subject in both splits).

If train loss is decreasing whilst validation loss is increasing then you've moved past the point where the model has the best generalization. So on your chart this seems to happen at epoch 2 since it sort of looks like your training loss is still decreasing but your validation loss is increasing.

So to say the same thing a different way, this means that model model has started to focus on training features that don't generalize to the validation/hold-out data.

See https://machinelearningmastery.com/overfitting-machine-learning-models/ for more exaggerated cases.

Answer (score 2):

Having smaller train loss than validation loss does not necessarily imply overfitting. It is very common and is considered totally okay in most cases. It would be more concerning if the validation loss was going down and then significantly start going back up, while the train loss keeps going down.

From your plots, it seems that your validation loss is going up a little bit but I don't think it is significant enough. One option is training for longer and seeing if the validation loss keeps going up. From your task, dataset size and split and validation accuracy, I would say most likely you have no overfitting. Could be interesting to look at the validation accuracy after epoch 2 and see if it is higher than your accuracy after epoch 4. If so, I believe we could argue that you model has a small amount of overfitting yes. However, when are at 99% accuracy range, we can attribute these increases or decrease of val loss to small statistical fluctuations that are not necessarily overfitting.